# Locking document after approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, check-out, content-approval, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have created a document approval workflow. Now I want to add a condition that once the document is approved the document should get locked ie. no one is able to make any changes in it. it should only be available in read only mode to everyone including the document creator.

I used check-out feature but in that the person who triggered the approval flow has the option to check-in the file and make it available to other for editing.

Comment: Are you using a SharePoint workflow or Power Automate flow?

Comment: @CallumCrowley I am using Sharepoint Workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Declare record" action in SharePoint 2013 workflows which you could use to declare the document a record. Nobody would be able to make changes to the document once it has been declared a record.

Comment: Hey! I can see Workpoint -Declares a document as a record (preview) [Premium].
What does preview premium means? Sorry but I'm a newbie to sharepoint.

Comment: When I click on it I get this
Failed with error: 'AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service ('https://workpoint365.dk/WorkPoint365.WebAPI') that your organization has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions. '. Please sign in again.

Comment: @RichaMohan 1. “Preview” stands for “Public preview”, which means that this feature is not yet released and currently under testing. You might experience unstable performance or issues while using this feature. 2. “Premium” means this feature requires a premium Power Automate license, and so is the error suggests. The feature/connector is not included in the Standard/Free plan for Power Automate. See a reference here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq#power-automate

Answer (score 0):

The *Declare Record* and *Undeclare Record* actions are [deprecated in SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/what-s-changed-in-sharepoint-designer#sharepoint-2010-workflow-platform), so you will not be able to use them in SharePoint Online since 2010 workflows are no longer supported.

---

The [Record Declaration feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configuring-in-place-records-management-7707a878-780c-4be6-9cb0-9718ecde050a) is still available though, which is the most quick and efficient way to lock a document for good.

Activate "**In Place Records Management**" feature via *Site collection features*. After that, go to *Site Settings* > *Record declaration settings* and select "Block Edit and Delete" under Record Restrictions.

Then go to the document library > *Library settings* > *Record declaration settings* and select “Never allow the manual declaration of records”. Also decide if you want to enable “Automatic Declaration”.

---

If you are open for Power Automate solution, here is a post you can refer to for workaround: [SharePoint Online rest api to declare item as record.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254557/sharepoint-online-rest-api-to-declare-item-as-record)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the document to PDF and archive it then. This should be a safe way to prevent any further changes.

There are several connectors in PA for this action.